# Combine "Year", "Month", and "Day" columns in Biqquery to a Date column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to the bigquery. I was looking into the public dataset `gsod`, which has three different columns, i.e., `year`, `month`, and `day`. Can I change this to a single column called `date` in format `yyyy-mm-dd`?

I saw you could do something like

```
SELECT
  DATE(2016, 12, 25) AS date_ymd
```

But how do I pass columns inside `DATE` instead of a single value? I want to combine the query with the following simple query and get a column called `date`.

```
SELECT
*,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
SELECT date(year, month, day) as date_ymd, *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod`
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Is there also a way to directly drop the year, months, and day column?

Comment: yes. use `SELECT date(year, month, day) as date_ymd, * except(year, month, day)`